# Отображение строк в виде таблиц

Tags: android, android-studio

Из sqlite получаю строку в таком виде:
"имя1;фамилия1;отчество1
имя2;фамилия2;отчество2
имя3;фамилия3;отчество3
имя4;фамилия4;отчество4"
Она отображается как строка в в TextView. Возможно сделать так, чтоб она отображалась в виде таблички?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо создать RecyclerView в котором каждый элемент будет состоять из трёх TextView в каждое из которых вы будете вносить данные из БД.
Получиться список, каждая строка которого будет содержать имя, фамилию, отчество.

Но для большего удобства, я бы посоветовал хранить данные в БД не строкой, а завести отдельные столбцы для id, имя, фамилия, отчество и забирать всё в список, например создав класс `data class Person(val name: String, val surname: String, val patronymic: String)` получать `List<Person>`.
Посмотрите примеры создания RecyclerView и заполнения его из БД

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте получать сразу через List<> и заполнять ListView циклом.

Answer (score 0):

Таблица рисуется примерно так

```
<TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/b27"
                android:text="Год "
                android:background="#D8E4BC"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="1px"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/c27"
                android:layout_margin="1px"
                android:background="#D8E4BC"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Тело рассрочки "
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="12dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/d27"
                android:text="Взнос "
                android:background="#D8E4BC"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="1px"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/e27"
                android:text="Ежемесячно "
                android:background="#D8E4BC"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="1px"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textColor="#000"/>
        </TableRow>
```